# eclipse failed to load jne shared library

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I had copied the eclipse for android sdk bundle from my friend laptop, it works on his laptop and show an error as "JNI shared library for the path of the java and jre folder".

Am using 64bit version windows 7 os, and i had installed java 64bit version only in the path "c:/program files/java"
in environment variable too it was added.

why the error proceeds??

Comment: Can you provide some more info about is it working on friends laptop and not working on your laptop, possibly provide logcat

Comment: my friend copied the bundle extracted folder(not zipped) from someone else and he had downloaded the plugins for the version and using in it. were the copied the exact folder he is using ( memory of 600 something MB). while i opend the the eclipse.exe file am getting this error.

Comment: the error show like

Failed to load JNI Shared Library "c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll

I like to know that do server folder present inside \jdk\bin ....??
in my pc i have two folders inside java
1. jdk
2. jre

i also having jre folder inside the jdk1.7.0_71 folder too..

Kindly explain me the details of all the above, am a new user so i cant upload the screenshot here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am Not aware about whats the problem is, but i downloaded the eclipse luna and set the same path of the workspace and the java and jre path in the eclipse luna and am using it, i works now.